# Autowired Repository null in Controller for a Spring Boot application

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-data

I am writing a Spring Boot application with a REST service based on jersey.

My repository interface is as below

```
@Repository
public interface ConnectionRepository extends CrudRepository<Connection, Integer>
{


}
```

My REST service is as follows

```
@Component
@Path("/conn")
public class ConnectionService
{
    @Autowired
    private ConnectionRepository cer;

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getSpConnection(@PathParam("id") String tid) throws Exception
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        if(cer == null)
        {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("Hello World").build();
        }
        Connection conendpoint = cer.find(tid);
        if(conendpoint == null)
        {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
        }
        else
        {
            String jsonConn = gson.toJson(conendpoint);
            return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(jsonConn).build();
        }

    }
}
```

Application.java

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
@Import(PersistenceContext.class)
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

PersistenceContext contains information for datasource and other beans.

Whenever I access this REST service, I get ConnectionRepository as null and the response is "Hello World". I am using `spring-boot-starter-web`,`spring-boot-starter-jersey` and `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.

What am I missing?

Comment: make sure the package of ConnectionRepository & ConnectionService is a same or subpackage of Application.java

Comment: Show your application configuration. You should be using the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, have the repository in the same package as the annotated class and remove the `@Repository` annotation from the interface. Also make sure a data source is configured or the JPA auto configuration will not be enabled.

Comment: @lenicliu - Application.java is in com.example.connection package, ConnectionRepository is in com.example.connection.repositories and ConnectionService is in com.example.connection.rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding following dependency in my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```